# uploadify returns back http error 302

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, uploadify

I am using uploadify on my asp.net mvc3 project.  I tested my code on local pc, it works. after I uploaded it to the production server, it returned back http error 302.

I found a few ppl got same problem, but they were using [authorize] attribute, that causes redirection.  I am not using it.  and I did get it working properly on my local. what else should I check?

Comment: Can you provide an HTTP request trace?